# Datepicker with ranges and flexible recurring selections

Tags: open-source, javascript, calendar, jquery

I can't seem to find what I'm looking for and I'm hoping someone else will know of a solution. I could always build it myself but I feel like it should have been done before.

### **Platform**

Web (client side). I'm looking for a jquery widget or something equivalent. Must be open source. This is for a commercial web app licensed under GPL so anything compatible with that works (MIT, for example).

### **Context**

The app is for booking/reserving things. I'd be more specific but it's designed to be fairly general purpose.

### **Requirements**

- Allows a date range selection from a visual calendar (like jquery datepicker)
- Allows for **recurring date definition**.
- Recurring date definition should allow the user to do the following type "date selections":

  - 25 of august - every year
  - Every monday from 02/05/2014 - 02/09/2014
  - First monday of every month from x to y
  - Monday to Wednesday every week from x to y
  - etc
  - or as close to this as I can get to this
- How it achieves this is flexible, though I need it as user friendly as possible.

### **Bonus Req**

- Allows time selection/repetition as well (I can add this myself though)

Comment: Did you ever came across this? http://mooman.github.io/recurring_dates/demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [recurring_dates javascript library](https://github.com/mooman/recurring_dates) written by Rachot Moragraan. It is open source. See the demo [here](http://mooman.github.io/recurring_dates/demo.html).

You can generate recurring date on every possible constraint.
For example:

- Every 2 weeks on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday starting today for 5 occurrences
- Every month on the last Sunday starting on 02/10/09 until 03/30/10

This library will generate a list of dates for those patterns.
It can also be a boiler plate code if you want to build or extend new functionalities.

With little CSS tweaks, you can make it look a bit friendly.

Comment: This hasn't been updated in a very long time, and seems broken - the demo page says "Recurrence is not defined" for any input.

Answer (score 1):

While looking at and researching Sri's recommendation, I also came across the [jQuery recurrenceinput widget](https://github.com/collective/jquery.recurrenceinput.js).

It looks like http://jquer.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/recurrence-input.jpg[image]

Thought I'd add it incase anyone is looking for an alternative.